# Assets - How to show file hierarchy

Tags: assets

After getting files properly indexed on the backend, how can they be displayed through a template on the front-end using the two assets:folders and assets:files?

If the file structure looks like this on the server:
Folder A 
- file1 
- file2 
- Folder B 
-- file3 
-- file4 
--- Folder C 
---- file5 
---- file6

... and was indexed with Assets, using their tags how could I display that in an unordered nested list?  Th example on their site with folders and files is close, but isn't nested.  The end goal is a browsable download page with EE goodness.  If not, is there a better way with navigation, maybe like their backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets 2.1 is out and for me it works like this:

```
<ul>
    {exp:assets:folders parent_folder="{filedir_}"}
        <li>{folder_name}</a>
            {if total_subfolders}
                <ul>
                    {subfolders}
                </ul>
            {/if}
            <ul>
                {exp:assets:files folder_id="{folder_id}"}
                        <li><a href="{url}">{if title != ""}{title}{if:else}{filename}{/if} ({size})</a></li>
                {/exp:assets:files}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {/exp:assets:folders}
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, I was all over the 2.1 update.  Thanks!